# Simple `foldM` Example

Tags: haskell

Looking at `foldM`:

`foldM :: Monad m => (a -> b -> m a) -> a -> [b] -> m a`

I tried to create an example of `foldM` that simply appended each element of the list `[1,2,3]` to itself.

Based on my initial (wrong) understanding of `foldM`, I expected `[[1], [2], [3]]` as the output of the following:

```
ghci> let f = (\xs x -> [x] : [xs])
```

But, I was wrong:

```
ghci> foldM f [] [1,2,3]
[[3],[2],[3],[1],[3],[2],[3],[]]
```

Please explain what's going on in this example.

Comment: What you want is just a regular fold.  Try using `foldl` instead of `foldM`, and then try using `f = (\xs x -> return (x : xs))` with `foldM`. Then see what you can do with `f` to see how it interacts with various monads.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

After reading the documentation and tweaking a bit with `foldM` in GHCi, I think I can explain what happened in your example. Let's reexamine the type signature of `foldM`:

```
foldM :: Monad m => (a -> b -> m a) -> a -> [b] -> m a
```

From this type signature, we can conclude that `foldM` takes a function `(a -> b -> m a)` and applies it to each element of a list (`[b]`). The second parameter is the initial value passed to the function in the "first call". Subsequent calls use the resulting value of applying the function (the one "extracted" from `m a`).

Thus, when you do:

```
ghci> let f = (\xs x -> [x] : [xs])
ghci> foldM f [] [1,2,3]
[[3],[2],[3],[1],[3],[2],[3],[]]
```

It is equivalent to:

```
ghci> ([] `f` 1) >>= (`f` 2) >>= (`f` 3)
ghci> [[3],[2],[3],[1],[3],[2],[3],[]]
```

If we break the line above into the following subexpressions we can see more clearly what's going on:

```
ghci> ([] `f` 1)
ghci> [[1],[]]
ghci> ([] `f` 1) >>= (`f` 2)
ghci> [[2],[1],[2],[]]
...
```

The function `f` takes a list and a value as arguments, creates a singleton list (putting the value in its own list) and adds it to a list of lists. Initially, when we have an empty list, the result is obvious: `[[1],[]]` (which is our `"m a"` in the type signature). Now, as I said before, in order to call `f` again it's necessary to take the new `"a"` value from that result. This time, we call `f` passing the extracted value and the next value in the supplied list (i.e. `2` from `[1,2,3]`). The question is, considering our `"m a"` is `[[1],[]]`, which list should we pass as the first argument to `f`: `[1]` or `[]`? And the answer relies on the behaviour of the `>>=` operator for lists, which can be viewed as non-deterministic computations, that applies the given function to each element in the given list and combines the results. For this specific step in the example, `f` will be called twice for two different first parameters: `f [1] 2` and `f [] 2`.

I tried to answer the question based on the example given by the author, but the monadic chain used to explicit the behaviour of `foldM` in this particular case can be used to reason about any Monad.

Comment: nice explanation - maybe you should add the link to the doc/source of `foldM`

Comment: Good explanation. It's as simple as realize the accumulator is a list monad and how it *binds*. Not long ago there was a question about `forM` applied with function resulting in list monad.