# foldM with monad State does not type check

Tags: haskell, fold

- Existing questions about `foldM` (e.g. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31084771/understanding-foldm) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25517414/simple-foldm-example)) don't address the `State` monad.
- [The docs](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.19.1.0/docs/Control-Monad.html#v:foldM) don't specify examples, and I can't compile even a simple example.

```hs
import Control.Monad.State.Lazy
import Control.Monad ( foldM )

data Student = Student { name :: String, sid :: Int } deriving ( Show )
data TestResult = TestResult { tested :: Student, grade :: Int } deriving ( Show )
data Classroom = Classroom { students :: [ Student ] } deriving ( Show )

test :: Student -> State Classroom TestResult
test s = do { c <- get; put c { students = s:(students c) }; return $ TestResult { tested = s, grade = 2 * (sid s) } }

tests :: [ Student ] -> State Classroom [ TestResult ]
tests = mapM test

worst :: State Classroom TestResult
worst = return $ TestResult { tested = Student { name = "MMM", sid = 0 }, grade = 0 }

better :: TestResult -> TestResult -> State Classroom TestResult
better r1 r2 = return $ case (grade r1) < (grade r2) of { True -> r2; False -> r1 }

brightest :: [ Student ] -> State Classroom TestResult
brightest students = foldM better worst (tests students)

main = print $ evalState (brightest [ Student "X" 19, Student "Y" 49, Student "Z" 46 ]) (Classroom [])
```

Here are the errors I get - what am I missing ?

```hs
Main.hs:22:35: error: [GHC-83865]
    • Couldn't match type ‘StateT
                             Classroom Data.Functor.Identity.Identity TestResult’
                     with ‘TestResult’
      Expected: TestResult
        Actual: State Classroom TestResult
    • In the second argument of ‘foldM’, namely ‘worst’
      In the expression: foldM better worst (tests students)
      In an equation for ‘brightest’:
          brightest students = foldM better worst (tests students)
   |
22 | brightest students = foldM better worst (tests students)
   |                                   ^^^^^

Main.hs:22:42: error: [GHC-83865]
    • Couldn't match type ‘[TestResult]’ with ‘TestResult’
      Expected: StateT
                  Classroom Data.Functor.Identity.Identity TestResult
        Actual: State Classroom [TestResult]
    • In the third argument of ‘foldM’, namely ‘(tests students)’
      In the expression: foldM better worst (tests students)
      In an equation for ‘brightest’:
          brightest students = foldM better worst (tests students)
   |
22 | brightest students = foldM better worst (tests students)
   |                                          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Comment: Please do yourself a favour and put your code in a `.hs` file rather than defining everything in GHCi...

Comment: ``foldM `better` worst (tests students)`` calls function `better` with first argument `foldM` and second argument `worst (tests stuents)`. I think this is not what you intended. To start, remove the backticks.

Comment: @chi you're completely right, I removed them. But my code still doesn't compile - I'll edit the new errors I get

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `foldM` function only expects the first argument to produce a monadic value. The second and third arguments should be normal values. So you need to do some unwrapping:

```
worst :: TestResult
worst = TestResult { tested = Student { name = "MMM", sid = 0 }, grade = 0 }

brightest :: [ Student ] -> State Classroom TestResult
brightest students = do
  ts <- tests students
  foldM better worst ts
```